# Checkbox select trigger not working, but if I put alert it is working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling a javascript method where I am triggering the `check-box`. If I just call

```
$("input[name='SelectSubscription']:first").trigger('click');`
```

then check-box select not happening. but if I do alert before this call I am able to see the check-box selection.

```
if ("@processType" === "JOIN") {
    alert("CallCheckboxClick");
    $("input[name='SelectSubscription']:first").trigger('click');
}
```

It is strange. How to resolve this?

Edit:

HTML code

```
<div style="float: left;height:60px; vertical-align:middle">
    <br />
    <span>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="SelectSubscription" value="@oSubscription.ProductId;@hdnRateCode;@hdnRatePrice" id="@oSubscription.ProductId" @selectItem @disabled >&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
       
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide code HTML?

Comment: added html code

Comment: That `if` statement doesn't show anything from the checkbox. It's comparing two strings, and the condition should fail. Is `@processType` something that gets replaced by a framework?

Comment: Agreed with @Barmar here. `if ("@processType" === "JOIN") {` will always fail until some replacement happen over `@processType`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the jQuery cdn? It looks like it is working fine.

```js
alert("The checkbox is selected");
$("input[name='SelectSubscription']:first").trigger('click');
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="SelectSubscription" value="@oSubscription.ProductId;@hdnRateCode;@hdnRatePrice" id="@oSubscription.ProductId" @selectItem @disabled >&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Do you really think he forgot to add the jQuery library? Did you even check his code fully? Don't you think you just posted a no-use answer in a hurry? Your first query needs to be what is this : `if ("@processType" === "JOIN") {`

Comment: What you just said was one of my thoughts too but then another question arises "If the condition is not met then how the first line is being executed?"

Comment: So in case of confusion, you have to ask via comment, not post an answer. Btw lets see what OP respond